# How can I get a wildcard appended to a substring of a DAC field?

Tags: acumatica

The screen I'm customizing is the 'Requests' screen (RQ301000) - and I want to modify the Vendor lookup in the grid to be based on the Request class chosen in the header.  I already know how to modify the Vendor selector to include a filter, as I have done this on the Requisitions screen - but that customization included adding a user field for Request Class (which doesn't exist on the Requisitions screen).

I do have code that I obtained previously that gets a wildcard appended value of a field.  The problem is, this code used a User field that was in the same DAC as the wildcard field - The code is shown below:

```
public class RQRequisitionExt : PXCacheExtension<RQRequisition>
{
    #region UsrRequestClass
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "NSA Request Class", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(RQRequestClass.reqClassID), DescriptionField = typeof(RQRequestClass.descr))]
    public virtual string UsrRequestClass { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrRequestClass : IBqlField {}
    #endregion


    //This is a DAC field that creates / tacks on a wildcard to the end of the UsrRequestClass field above...
    public abstract class myFieldWildcard : IBqlField { };
    [PXString(30, IsUnicode = true)]
    public virtual string MyFieldWildcard
    {
        [PXDependsOnFields(typeof(usrRequestClass))]
        get
        {
            //return PXDatabase.Provider.SqlDialect.WildcardAnything + UsrRequestClass + PXDatabase.Provider.SqlDialect.WildcardAnything;
            if (UsrRequestClass != null)
                return PXDatabase.Provider.SqlDialect.WildcardAnything + UsrRequestClass.Substring(0, 2) + PXDatabase.Provider.SqlDialect.WildcardAnything;
            else
                return UsrRequestClass;
        }
    }


}
```

For what I'm trying to do on the Requests screen, I'm not using a user field for this - I'm using the Request Class field already on the screen - but I have no idea how to get the value of this field to use in the wildcard 'get' routine.

Essentially, I want to obtain the Request Class value on the screen and use it in this wildcard field to return to my modified Vendor selector (not shown - but done using a CacheAttached event).

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, for me, was to redefine the Request Class field in the same DAC extension that contained the wildcard field, as follows:

```
public class RQRequestExt : PXCacheExtension<RQRequest>
{

    //Redefine the Request Class in this DAC extension
    #region ReqClassID
    public abstract class reqClassID : IBqlField {}
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXDefault(typeof(RQSetup.defaultReqClassID))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Request Class", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(RQRequestClass.reqClassID), DescriptionField = typeof(RQRequestClass.descr))]
    public virtual string ReqClassID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    //This is a DAC field that creates / tacks on a wildcard to the end of the UsrRequestClass field above...
    public abstract class rQRequestwildcard : IBqlField { };
    [PXString(30, IsUnicode = true)]
    public virtual string RQRequestwildcard
    {
        [PXDependsOnFields(typeof(RQRequest.reqClassID))]
        get
        {
            if (ReqClassID != null)
                return PXDatabase.Provider.SqlDialect.WildcardAnything + ReqClassID.Substring(0, 2) + PXDatabase.Provider.SqlDialect.WildcardAnything;
            else
                return PXDatabase.Provider.SqlDialect.WildcardAnything;
        }
    }
}
```

This way I have a reference to the Request Class ID used in the Wildcard field operation...